# Is a landlord of a large rental building, where people of all denominations live, allowed to put a mezuzah on the entrance of the building?

Tags: mezuzah

Is a landlord of a large rental building, where people of all denominations live, allowed to put a mezuzah on the entrance of the building ? It seems to me that the mezuzah indicates that the building is a Jewish building, but there are many non Jews and secular Jews living in the building, many of whom object to the presence of the mezuzah. If the building had been owned by a Hindu, the corresonding symbol
would be a swastikah, turning in the direction opposite to the way it is displayed by the Nazis. In fact Hindus often do put this symbol in their homes, indicating prosperity , to the consternation of those ignorant of their practices, just as many non Jews are ignorant of the meaning of the mezuzah. I  am interested in how you would interpret this situation.

Comment: Welcome aboard @bennybonomo. It's a good question. I hope you get a great response.

Comment: I think halachic sources (_Rama_ IIRC) discuss whether one *must* put a _m'zuza_ on such a building. But maybe some discuss whether one *may*.

Comment: _he mezuzah indicates that the building is a Jewish building_. Wrong. The Mezuza indicates that the Jewish owner or tenant is fulfilling Gcd's will.

Answer (score 2):

The Ramma in Yoreh Deah siman 286 siff 1 brings the Mordechai and Aguda who say a house, yard or city which has some non-Jews is absolved from the mitzvah of mezuzah.

The Taz #3 there brings the reason as being a danger if the no-jews become afraid that there is magic being performed against them, as found in maseches Yoma 11.

Comment: Mr Danny Shoemann says that the presence of the mezuzah does not indicate the building is a Jewish building. But the shmah clearly states that Elohim is the one true God, while not accepting the worship of other religions. If there was a statement and recognition and unification of all worship, then that would be ecumenical, but I have never seen anything expressing directly that ecumenical belief in Judaism. If anything, it always seems exclusive. In addition, what if someone is an atheistic or agnostic. What if one or all of the lamed vovnicks were atheists They too can perform mitxvahs

Answer (score 1):

The mezuzah is not put on the bulding to *"indicate that the building is a Jewish building"* (as far as I know)

It is put their to fulfill the [commandment](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/mezuzah1.html) and for protection.

If it causes problems (*consternation*) we hide it in the doorpost (in America it usually does not cause problems)

*"swastikah, turning in the direction opposite to the way it is displayed by the Nazis",* does not bother me/us (if it is pagan I will just avoid looking on it)

See.
http://www.haaretz.com/news/israel/idf-rabbinate-shows-non-jews-the-door-in-mezuzah-book-ruling.premium-1.516604?v=8EFCEF3558FB1B948186DA38078E184E